# Finding a Model with Params other than ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-directory, strong-parameters

I'm using Rails 4 with strong parameters to try to find a user by a parameter called "provider_id".
The hope is that I'll be able to make a call with my API to a URL such as:

url.com/api/v1/user?provider=facebook?provider_id=12345

My routes are as follows: **routes.rb**

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
        resources :users
        match '/:provider/:provider_id', to: 'users#find_by_provider', via: 'get'
    end
end
```

My Strong parameters are:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location, :provider, :provider_id) if params[:user]
end
```

My Function is:

```
def find_by_provider
    @user = User.find(params[:provider_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @user }
    end
end
```

Currently, I'm testing with:
url.com/api/v1/facebook/12345
and it is returning:

```
"{"provider"=>"facebook",
"provider_id"=>"12345"}"
```

which is good! But I now get the error: "Couldn't find User with id=12345"

Also, somewhat related: occasionally I receive an error that says "param not found: user".

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
@user = User.find(params[:provider_id])
```

To:

```
@user = User.find_by(:provider_id => params[:provider_id])
```

Comment: How is this different from Luke's answer above?

Comment: @eightonrose this returns the single Activerecord object you are querying for while Luke's answer returns a relation object that's why he needs to call `take` on it to retrieve the first item from the relation

Comment: is this faster than where?

Comment: The only difference is that you are not chaining methods in this case

Comment: @eightonrose it would be nice to select one of the answers as the correct answer and upvote them, so the question would be regarded as closed, you could be nice to upvote all the correct answers as well

Answer (score 1):

find method will alyways search objects with the id column. Use the `where` method to search by other criterias/columns

Use:

```
@user = User.where(provider_id: params[:provider_id]).take
```

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html if you want to learn more about the active record query interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example where to use `find_by!` (note the `!`).

```
@user = User.find_by!(:provider_id => params[:provider_id])
```

It works like `find_by` and returns one `User`. But if the user is not found it raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. That exception is handled by Rails automatically and is turned into a 404 error page.